# 2 queries in 1 output

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get these 2 queries into one query and...

```
select  cp.TouchedWhen,
        U.DisplayName AS 'ATTENDING'
from    SXAAMBClientPrescription CP (nolock)
    inner join CV3User U (nolock) on U.GUID = CP.CareproviderGUID
Order by CP.TouchedWhen ASC

select  cp.TouchedWhen,
        U.DisplayName AS 'RESIDENT'
from SXAAMBClientPrescription CP (nolock)
        inner join CV3User U (nolock) on U.GUID = CP.UserGUID
order by CP.TouchedWhen ASC
```

the output should be:

```
TouchedWhen | Attending | Resident

9/16/13     | Dr Joe    | Resident Schmo
```

If TouchedWhen matches in the 2 queries the Attending and the Resident should be in the same row like above. Otherwise fill attending and resident however they show up.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include the code you've tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cp.TouchedWhen
     , U1.DisplayName As ATTENDING
     , U2.DisplayName As RESIDENT
FROM   SXAAMBClientPrescription As CP (NOLOCK)
 LEFT
  JOIN CV3User As U1 (NOLOCK)
    ON U1.GUID = CP.CareproviderGUID
 LEFT
  JOIN CV3User As U2 (NOLOCK)
    ON U2.GUID = CP.UserGUID
ORDER
    BY CP.TouchedWhen ASC
```

This will return a row for every `TouchedWhen` even if there's no matching `UserGUID` or `CareproviderGUID`. If you only want results with both just change the join types to `INNER`

Answer (score 0):

You can use FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
select cp.TouchedWhen, t1.ATTENDING, t2.RESIDENT
from 
(select  cp.TouchedWhen AS TouchedWhen,
        U.DisplayName AS ATTENDING
from    SXAAMBClientPrescription CP (nolock)
    inner join CV3User U (nolock) on U.GUID = CP.CareproviderGUID
Order by CP.TouchedWhen AS) t1

FULL OUTER JOIN     
(select  cp.TouchedWhen AS TouchedWhen,
        U.DisplayName AS RESIDENT
from SXAAMBClientPrescription CP (nolock)
        inner join CV3User U (nolock) on U.GUID = CP.UserGUID
order by CP.TouchedWhen ASC) t2

on t1.TouchedWhen = t2.TouchedWhen;
```

Comment: Psst... you're outer `SELECT` is going to return literal strings ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind rows with neither `attending` or `resident` then remove the `where` clause:

```
select  
    cp.TouchedWhen,
    u.DisplayName as 'ATTENDING',
    r.DisplayName as 'RESIDENT'
from
    SXAAMBClientPrescription cp (nolock)
        left outer join 
    CV3User u (nolock) 
        on u.GUID = cp.CareproviderGUID
        left outer join
    CV3User r (nolock) 
         on r.GUID = cp.UserGUID
where
    u.guid is not null or
    r.guid is not null
order by 
    cp.TouchedWhen
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also UNION both selects:

```
SELECT TouchedWhen, MIN(ATTENDING), MIN(RESIDENT)
FROM
 (
   SELECT  cp.TouchedWhen,
           U.DisplayName AS 'ATTENDING'
           CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(40) AS 'RESIDENT'
   FROM    SXAAMBClientPrescription CP (nolock)
       INNER JOIN CV3User U (nolock) ON U.GUID = CP.CareproviderGUID
   UNION ALL    
   SELECT  cp.TouchedWhen,
           CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(40) AS 'ATTENDING'
           U.DisplayName AS 'RESIDENT'
   FROM SXAAMBClientPrescription CP (nolock)
           INNER JOIN CV3User U (nolock) ON U.GUID = CP.UserGUID
 ) as dt
GROUP BY TouchedWhen
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```